# Break on exception using testng

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, testng, breakpoints

I was working with Eclipse and testNG in java with my own classes and one thing I wanted to do is breaking on uncaught exception only.  I went into Eclipse and set up a few exception breakpoints, but it seems testNG swallows those exceptions so having breakpoints on uncaught exceptions doesn't work.  Of course I can always enable "suspend on caught location" to catch every exception thrown, but that wouldn't be very effective debugging.  Can anyone familiar with testNG and Eclipse guide me on how to bypass this problem?